# How to serialize Map to <key>value</key> using Java Simple Xml

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

How can I convert a `map` into `list` of `key` elements with `value` text using Java simple xml ?

```
<list>
<key1>val1</key1>
<key2>val2</key2>
<key3>val3</key3>
...
</li>
```

Comment: Do you try something? Look at `map.keySet()`, it will give you a set of `key` from a `map`, then you can interact to create your XML. If you have problems, post your code and I can help.

Comment: Yes I can get the key, value and create my own xml using StringBuilder or some other string manipulation, if i understand you correctly. Thanks for trying, but I don't think that is the answer I am looking for.